# Elastic Search Java Connectivity

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am very new to Elasticsearch and when ever I try to get all the indices from Elasticsearch from Java, it is throwing a connection close exception.

Dependency I am using:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code:

```java
static RestClient httpClient;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "pass"));

    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
        @Override
        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
            return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        }
    });

     httpClient = builder.build();

    JacksonJsonpMapper jsonMapper = new JacksonJsonpMapper();

    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(httpClient, jsonMapper);

    ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

 System.out.println(client.cat().indices());

    httpClient.close();
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:908)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:299)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:146)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.cat.ElasticsearchCatClient.indices(ElasticsearchCatClient.java:405)
    at Runner.main(Runner.java:52)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?